# Load files to Azure file storage using python

Tags: python, azure, storage

I'm using azure file storage for data persistence of several container instances, on that side, it is working fine.  I issue I have is that some of the containers read data that I load manually to the File storage via web interface. I need to update this to be able to load the files from python but I'm not finding any examples of how to to this.

There is a github repo from Azure https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python that is supposed to handle that, but I'm not finding any examples there, only the source code. On medium and other sites I have found tutorials for using Blob but I haven't found any for Files

Comment: What you do mean "read data"? get the content of the file or download the file in the storage File?

Comment: You can find some sample code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/tree/master/samples/file and also here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-python-how-to-use-file-storage. HTH.

Comment: Any more questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment said, the [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/tree/master/samples/file) show the action for the file share. I assume that you want to read the content from the file which in the file share, the same code below:

```
from azure.storage.file import FileService

storageAccount='xxxxx'
accountKey='xxxxx'

file_service = FileService(account_name=storageAccount, account_key=accountKey)

# if the file in the root path of the share, please let the directory name as ''
file = file_service.get_file_to_text(share_name, directory_name, file_name)
print(file.content)
```

This code gets the file with type [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file/azure.storage.file.models.file?view=azure-python).